# Selecting array of unique results from database and using them foreach

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I'm trying to get an array of unique rows from my database and use them in a foreach for a dropdown menu, but I have never ever touched arrays or the foreach function. I thought I was getting it, but this code doesn't seem to work. I couldn't find anything on the site or web on this subject so I turn to you for help. Thanks in advance.

```
<select name='item'>
<?php
$getItems = $data->query('SELECT * FROM items WHERE id != "'.$sellId.'"');

while($row = $getItems->fetch_assoc()) {
    $getItems_2 = $data->query('SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE itemId = "'.$row['id'].'"');
    $raw = $getItems_2->fetch_assoc();
    $raw = array_unique($raw['itemId']));
    foreach ($raw as $value) {
        echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: for a start use a join not 2 queries

Comment: Can you explain the problem in a bit more detail? Particularly what you mean by "doesn't seem to work."

Comment: `SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE itemId != $sellId GROUP BY (whatever_column_you_want_to_be_unique)`

Comment: `$raw['itemId']` is the same as `$row['id']`. Why do you need to fetch it from the other table?

Comment: `$raw` just contains one row from `inventory`. Why are you looping through it? And `$raw['itemId']` is not an array.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I now realize it was a dumb question. Solution: SELECT items.id, items.name FROM items INNER JOIN inventory ON inventory.itemId = items.id GROUP BY (items.id) HAVING items.id != "'.$sellId.'"